# [WP8.1]Windows Phone [8.1] - PivotItem Layout Update only on Selecting PivotItem

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, pivot

Question related to UI (it's been so nice time sitting deep in backend).

Some introduction:

In my project I have MainPage with Pivot Control containing 3 PivotItems. There is also one additional page, let's call it AddPage.

There are two DataSources with relationship between.

PivotItem number 2 has capability to delete items from DataSource_01. When that happens, DataSource_02 re-calculate its content and returns new updated collection for PivotItem number 1. This doesn't add new items to DataSource_02 though, it just changes some properties (currently DataSource_01 has 160 items in 18 categories, Data source_02 keeps this 18 categories with corresponding category sum based on DataSource_01).

PivotItem number 1 holds GridView with items source binded to DataSource_02. Tapping an item fires AddPage that has capability to add items to DataSource_01.

That's simplified logic and it works.

The problem is the LayoutUpdate. After removing item from DataSource_01 on PivotItem_02 when I slide to PivotItem_01 I can see each GridViewItem popping out one at a time. I have not convinced myself yet to accept this kind of behavior so here I am.

I would rather pre-load the view for the PivotItem_01 while still being on PivotItem_02. Maybe before update of PivotItem_02? Is there any way to control this behavior?

I have tried to run my Pivot's UpdateLayout() after database gets updated but it doesn't work.

There is also a twist.

I am writing my app for Windows 8.1 system, while testing it on my Microsoft Lumia 640LTE device with Windows 10. I have also another test device, Nokia Lumia 530 DS with Windows 8.1, and this one works fine, layout gets updated on PivotItem_01 before swiping to it.

I have added to one of the PivotItem_01 controls _SizeChanged event and handler. Handler runs on Windows_10 device when swiping to it while on Windows 8.1 device while updating PivotItem_02. It’s confusing but can be solved. I have also tried with new Data source with categories only and one record in DataSource_01 but it didn’t change anything.

I am not attaching any code while I think it’s not code related question.

Kind Regards,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

### Understanding the question

Alright I guess I've been able to understand the question. With your question did you mean: That the items in the `GridView` change when `Pivot.SelectedItem` is changed where as you want it to change as soon as your binded data changes. Also you don't want the items to get deleted one at a time, you want them to just go without any transitions. If that's what you mean then see the below solution.

### What's actually happening with the Pivot

The thing with `Pivot` control is it has `DefferedLoadingStrategy` inbuilt to it. So each time you change the selected tab the `LoadingStrategy` of the unselected Tab goes to `Lazy` because of which all the changes that happen to those particular data items do not take place untill the tab is selected again. Basically the view doesn't call for the updated data until it's selected.

### What's happening with the GridViewItems

In UWP the `GridView`has default `Transitions` with it. So when the data changes the content is updated with the Transitions defined by the control.

### The Solution:

For the `GridView`Items getting removed one at a time, you can type in something like this to avoid any Transitions.

```
<GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
     <TransitionCollection/>
</GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
```

[This Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e7b6b664-c4f8-4ebf-83a2-02751041ef5c/disable-listview-animation-when-items-update?forum=winappswithcsharp) would provide you with more insights about implementing the piece of code if you have a group style.

For the `Pivot` issue, I would recommend you not to use the `LayoutUpdated()` event as it would be called every time your view resizes or anything that changes even the slightest UI changes. Rather I would recommend using the `SelectionChanged` event on the `Pivot` control and name your `PivotItems` so that you can check the `Pivot.SelectedItem` property for applying different code logics on `SelectionChanged` event. You can use the `SelectionChanged`event with some logic like below:

```
if (pivot.SelectedItem == DetailsPivotItem)
{
   //Some Logic here. where DetailsPivotItem is the name of your PivotItem 
}
else
{
   // Some other logic here if you just have 2 PivotItems, if more then add elseIf statements
}
```

I hope this solves your query if not feel free to comment. thanks